# Python: Using requests for a webpage that redirects

Tags: python, html, python-requests

**Update: I did find the information I needed in the API, not really an answer to this specific question but a solution for my software.**

I'm trying to login to a webpage, navigate to another page, and parse an HTML table.

If you use the browser to go to the target page without being logged in, it takes you to the default landing page and you have to navigate to the target page anyway. That is why I have two URL calls.

```
import requests

payload = {'username' : 'USER', 'password' : 'PASSWORD'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('login_url', data=payload)
    r = s.get('target_url')
```

When you navigate to the login page, it normally goes to another page to check your browser before going to the login page itself. I get this response from 'p':

```
<span data-translate="checking_browser">Checking your browser before accessing</span> website.</h1>
<p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>
<p data-translate="allow_5_secs">Please allow up to 5 seconds…</p>
```

...which is just the page telling you to wait to be redirected and log in. Is there a way to handle this so that it waits for the page where it can log in? I will need to make this call about every 20 minutes in a code, so even better if I can stay logged in and only go for the target page.

- Ideal solution: Log in one time at beginning of program and stay logged in.
- Better solution: Re-log in each time but avoid the five second wait time to change pages.
- Acceptable solution: Wait the five seconds to be redirected prior to login each time.

Comment: We need real urls to help you

Comment: Try with stream = True, probably will let you in.

Answer (score 2):

This "checking your browser" message looks like a CloudFlare feature which is designed to stop people from accessing the site in this way - you will need to run some javascript from the server to pass this barrier (the idea being that someone accessing the site in a browser will have the javascript run automatically - if they're using a bot to scrape the site it'll fail)

. If the site has an API, switching to use that would be my first suggestion.

Otherwise, [there are packages to help you get around this issue](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape), but since the barriers are explicitly to prevent this kind of use, they're liable to stop working when CloudFlare makes changes.

Comment: OK thank you. They do have an API, which I use for everything else in the program. There is just one piece of information I need that is not returned in any of the API responses, so I am trying to find another way.